# facebook connect publish stream on tab application

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api

I really need your kind help about how to create a publish stream dialog inside your application tab.

I have this code snippet on my tab application: (tab.asp)

```
<div id="contentFooter">
            <ul>

                <li><fb:share-button class="url" href="<%=getConfig("AppURL")%>" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

that code snippet above was work, but what i want is some thing like this (in javascript):

```
function fb_publish() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: 'blah...',
        attachment: {
            name: 'name....',
            caption: 'Join NOW to WIN!',
            description: ('test'),
            href: '<%=getConfig("AppURL")%>'
        },action_links: [{
            text: 'Play Now!',
            href: '<%=getConfig("AppURL")%>'
        }],
        user_prompt_message: 'What’s on your mind?'
    },function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            //alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            //alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    });
}
```

but sadly..., on application tab, I can't put javascript (javascript is not working).
is there any way for me to achieve the same thing like my javascript code but inside fbml tag.

Thank you in Advance
AnD